# Execute Javascript of an email sended with python smtplib

Tags: javascript, python, html, smtp, smtplib

I'm practicing emailing and I wanted to know if it's possible to execute Javascript code when you send and email using smtplib and email libs, and when your message contain HTML code ?

It seem that nothing append.

HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
</div>
   <p class='Test'>This is my first sentence</p>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       var list = document.querySelector('p.Test');
       list.innerHTML = "I want to change it";
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Python Code:

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage


def ConnectServer(User, Pass, Host):
    SMTPServer = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(Host)
    SMTPServer.ehlo()
    SMTPServer.login(User, Pass)
    return SMTPServer

def SendMail(Server, src, dst, data):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = src
    msg['To'] = dst
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test envoi python'
    msg.add_alternative(data, 'html')
    Server.send_message(msg, src, dst)


def main():
    #Define email adresses
    me = 'AN_EMAIL@MAIL.com'
    me2 = 'AN_OTHER_EMAIL@mail.com'
    Server = ConnectServer(me, 'PASS', 'smtp.gmail.com')


    with open('HTML PATH HERE', 'r', encoding='utf8') as File:
        data = File.read()
        SendMail(Server, me, me2, data)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know we cant , i also tried to do this, i wanted to include a search bar for the table content in mail.

```
"No. JavaScript won't work in mails. A cool way to implement this feature 
 would be to include an image that points to your server, where you generate 
 the weather report server side and render it as an image, and return it to 
 the client.

 Note though that Gmail caches images and depending on when he does it that 
 might not be refreshed."
```

Source : https://www.quora.com/